# How to efficiently count totals for filter options

Tags: caching, filter

I am working on a webshop-type application. One feature I often see in other websites is a breakdown of filtering options, with after that a total of how many results that filtering option will have. You often see this on computer sites (e.g. Newegg) or used car sites. Example:

```
CPU:
  * AMD (315)
  * Intel (455)

Video card:
  * ATI (378)
  * Nvidia (402)
```

How can I efficiently calculate these totals? The website I a working on will have many different products (10.000+) with many different options. To make matters worse, the products are constantly changing.

Trying to precalculate all the different filtering combination totals seems unfeasable. If I have 5 different filters with 4 options each, the number of option possibilities would be `20 * 16 * 12 * 8 * 4 = 122880`. It would take a long time to calculate that.

Another option would be to query on-demand and cache the results (e.g. in Redis). But how could I manage the cache efficiently if products keep being added and removed? The caches would often be stale. I'm afraid I'd have to micro-manage cache invalidation somehow leading to a very complex and brittle implementation. The alternative would be to invalidate broad sections of cache. But immediately after invalidating, my database would be rushed by hunderds of queries from active users who need these totals recalculated.

Is there a nice and elegant way to handle this?

Comment: i assume they do it like google, mostly not correct total values :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no problem with showing live data for your case. Not to discourage you in any way, but 10K products is not a lot, performance wise. Several millions, on the other hand, is.

Did you actually try to implement it this way and found that it performs slowly, or you are just over-conscious about its theoretical performance? I suggest you do some stress-testing on your system AS IS, and see if it's worth improving. Still, here are some ideas to make it faster:

1. **Do not populate all counts at once**, only if specific category is expanded/clicked. So you would always end up with a single `SELECT cat_name, COUNT(*) GROUP BY cat_name` query, which should not take up much time. Single and relatively light query like this per user click sounds reasonable for me.
2. **Let the database engine manage caching for you**. If you perform similar queries often, your database engine should automatically optimize the underlying storage (i.e. move that whole table to memory or similar). You just need to make sure the instance has enough memory.
3. **Upgrade server hardware, if needed**. If the amount of data increases, you *may* not have enough memory to store everything. Don't panic yet, you can still put an SSD in, or install a 12 core Xeon processor into the server, depending on where the bottleneck is.

Comment: 4. Create the appropriate indexes. Telling ahead of time to your database engine that you will make queries of this kind improve the speed of the application. The database engine will use the indexes to do the operations more efficiently, with a small penalty on storage space.

Answer (score 0):

What about thinking from the othey way arround and keeping the numbers in the database? You could probably use triggers to automatically increment / decrement the counters in case a product is added to / removed from a given cathegory (if not, it can still be handled explicitly by the dialog that lets the store manager add / remove products on sale).

This seems like a good solution since a) i suppose the names of the cathegories are stored in the DB already so asking for the numbers incurs very little overhead, and b) even though the products are constantly changing, they are most likely changing with much lower frequency than is the frequency of requests (that still holds even if the users themselves can add/remove products). And finally c) there is no complicated caching scheme, the counters are being managed on a single place, by a single part of the code. Should be easy to keep it error-free.